# Webview not working as desired in case of HTML5 cache

Tags: android, html, caching, webview, titanium

I have created an application using Titanium Appcelerator in which I am using a webview to show some webpages. All the webpages to be displayed in the webview are HTML5 cache enabled, as I want the webpages to be available even when the application is running offline.

The problem which I am facing is that, the webview is not able to show the cached webpages when there is no network connection. But I have tested all the webpages in the browser, and all of them are working fine.

I am facing this problem for Android platform.

This is the code for the webview:

```
 //FirstView Component Constructor
function FirstView() {
    //create object instance, a parasitic subclass of Observable
    var self = Ti.UI.createView();




 var webview = Ti.UI.createWebView({
    url: 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryhtml5_html_manifest.htm'
});


self.add(webview);


    return self;
}

module.exports = FirstView;
```

The very url is working fine in the browser. How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use local html and it use jquery .ajax for load another webpage like that
    //inside local page

```
 <div id="pull"></div>
 <script>
 $.ajax({
 url: "http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryhtml5_html_manifest.htm",
 cache: true,type: "POST"}).done(function( html ) {
 $("#pull").append(html);  
 });
</script>
```